# "When" and indirect speech

Tags: reported-speech

This is the phrase I have:

Direct speech: *The world laughed when I told what I had seen.*

Indirect Speech: He said that the world had laughed when he (had) told what he had seen.

The question regarding the reported speech is, do I have to use "told" or "had told"?

Comment: The past perfect is often not used when the temporal relations are clear anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a backshifted sentence for reported speech, we don't backshift the contents of a when-clause if the time relative to now has not changed:

> "We will have a barbecue when you come" - *the visit is in the future*
> He said that we would have a barbecue when I go - *the visit is still in the future*.
> He said that we would have a barbecue when I went - *the visit is in the past*.

Looking at your sentences:

> "The world laughed when I told what I had seen." - *telling is in the past*
> He said that the world had laughed when he told what he had seen. *telling is still in the past*

As Jam Kay said, we generally avoid using past perfect if it's not strictly necessary. In your sentence, I think that it is necessary to distinguish between these two cases:

> "The world laughs when I tell what I have seen." - *still happens*
> He said that the world laughs when he tells what he has seen. -*still happens now, afaik*
> He said that the world laughed when he told what he had seen. - *still happened when he spoke to me*
>
> "The world laughed when I told what I had seen." - *no longer happens*
> He said that the world had laughed when he told what he had seen.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it this way:

"He said the world laughed when he told what he had seen."

The 'past perfect' does not need to be applied to every verb.

Comment: If the direct speech is: "The world laughs when I tell what I saw." then what the indirect speech equivalent would be? Is it also the same: "He said the world laughed when he told what he had seen."